# Custom adaptive loss function with additional dynamic argument in Keras

Tags: keras, loss-function

I have to use an adaptive custom loss function that takes an additional dynamic argument (`eps`)  in keras. The argument `eps` is a **scalar but changes from one sample to the other** : the loss function should be therefore adapted during training. I use a generator and I can pass this argument through every call of the generator during training (`generator_train[2]`). Based on answers to similar questions I tried to write the following wrapping:

```
def custom_loss(eps):
    def square_err(y_true, y_pred):
        nom = K.sum(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
        denom = eps**2
        loss = nom/denom
        return loss
    return square_err
```

But I am struggling with implementing it since `eps` is a dynamic variable: I don't know how I should pass this argument to the loss function during training (`model.fit`). Here is a simple version of my model:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(units=32, input_shape=(32, 4))
model.add(layers.Dense(units=1))
model.add_loss(custom_loss)
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(optimizer=opt)
history = model.fit(x=generator_train[0], y=generator_train[1],
                    steps_per_epoch=100
                    epochs=50,
                    validation_data=gen_vl,
                    validation_steps=n_vl)
```

Your help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass "sample weights", which will be `1/(eps**2)` for each sample.

Your generator should just output `x, y, sample_weights` and that's all.

Your loss can be:

```
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sum(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

In `fit`, you cannot use indexing in the generator, you will pass just `generator_train`, no `x`, no `y`, just `generator_train`.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel for your answer. Just to be sure that I understood you well : Should not I indicate any where that I want to pass the sample_weights ? It always takes x, y, and sample_weights in this order ?

Comment: @Basilique, yes, the generator outputs x, y, sample_weights in this order.